# While Enemy attacking he cant die

Tags: c#, monogame

I'm making a platform game in Monogame where I have enemies that make the attack frame when it should but if i try to kill it, it get stuck in the frame and cant die.

Here is my Game1 code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace TreasureHunt
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the main type for your game
    /// </summary>
    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {

        int enemyLives = 2;
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        SoundEffect aj;
        SoundEffect collect;
        Texture2D coinCount;

        int screenWidth = 1024;
        int screenHeight = 768;

        //int enemyLives = 2;
        //Vector2 temp = new Vector2 (1000, 600);

        Pirate player;

        List<EnemyPirate> argh = new List<EnemyPirate>();
        List<Coin> coin = new List<Coin>();
        bool firstPirateArmy = true;

        Level map;
        Vector2 dist;
        Vector2 coindist;
        Background backGround;
        int collectedCoins;
        SpriteFont inGameFont;

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = screenWidth;
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = screenHeight;
            graphics.IsFullScreen = false;
            Window.Title = "TreasureHunt";
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
        /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
        /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
        /// and initialize them as well.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void Initialize()
        {
            map = new Level (screenWidth, screenHeight);
            map.LoadMap (Content, 1);
            backGround = new Background(screenWidth, (int)(Level.GetWorldSize().X * Level.GetTileSize()), 1, Content);

            player = new Pirate(screenWidth, screenHeight, Content, graphics.GraphicsDevice);

            argh.Add(new EnemyPirate(screenWidth, screenHeight, Content, new Vector2(400, 400), enemyLives));
            argh.Add(new EnemyPirate(screenWidth, screenHeight, Content, new Vector2(1600, 420), enemyLives));
            argh.Add(new EnemyPirate(screenWidth, screenHeight, Content, new Vector2(3800, 600), enemyLives));
            coin.Add (new Coin (screenWidth, screenHeight, Content, new Vector2 (505, 278)));
            coin.Add (new Coin (screenWidth, screenHeight, Content, new Vector2 (1100, 25)));
            coin.Add (new Coin (screenWidth, screenHeight, Content, new Vector2 (890, 660)));
            coin.Add (new Coin (screenWidth, screenHeight, Content, new Vector2 (1720, 660)));
            coin.Add (new Coin (screenWidth, screenHeight, Content, new Vector2 (2348, 410)));
            coin.Add (new Coin (screenWidth, screenHeight, Content, new Vector2 (2850, 150)));
            coin.Add (new Coin (screenWidth, screenHeight, Content, new Vector2 (2950, 660)));

            base.Initialize();
        }


        private void ResetPirates()
        {
            if(firstPirateArmy)
            {
                argh.Add(new EnemyPirate(screenWidth, screenHeight, Content, new Vector2(1000, 500), enemyLives));
                argh.Add(new EnemyPirate(screenWidth, screenHeight, Content, new Vector2(1500, 50), enemyLives));
                argh.Add(new EnemyPirate(screenWidth, screenHeight, Content, new Vector2(3700, 200), enemyLives));
                firstPirateArmy = false;
            }
            else
            {
                argh.Add(new EnemyPirate(screenWidth, screenHeight, Content, new Vector2(400, 400), enemyLives));
                argh.Add(new EnemyPirate(screenWidth, screenHeight, Content, new Vector2(1600, 420), enemyLives));
                argh.Add(new EnemyPirate(screenWidth, screenHeight, Content, new Vector2(3800, 600), enemyLives));
                firstPirateArmy = true;
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
        /// all of your content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
            inGameFont = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("inGameFont");
            aj = Content.Load<SoundEffect> ("AjLjud");
            collect = Content.Load<SoundEffect> ("Collecting1");
            coinCount = Content.Load<Texture2D> ("Coin");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
        /// all content.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {
            // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
        /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // Allows the game to exit
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();

            player.Update (gameTime);
            for (int i = 0; i < coin.Count (); i++) {

                coin [i].Update (gameTime);
                coindist = (coin [i].GetPosition () - player.GetPosition ());

                if (coindist.Length () < 60) {
                    collect.Play ();
                    coin.RemoveAt (i);
                    collectedCoins++;
                }
            }  

            for (int i = 0; i < argh.Count (); i++) {
                dist = (argh [i].GetPosition () - player.GetPosition ());

                if (dist.Length () < 100) {
                    argh [i].Attack ();//.currentState = EnemyPirate.figureState.hitting;
                    player.playerLives--;    
                }      
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < argh.Count(); i++)
            {
                argh[i].Update(gameTime);
                if (player.HasHitEnemy(argh[i].GetBoundingBox()))
                {
                    argh [i].enemyLives--;
                    aj.Play ();
                    argh [i].hurt = true;
                    if (argh [i].enemyLives <= 0) {
                        argh [i].currentState = EnemyPirate.figureState.predie;
                        argh [i].EnemyIsDead ();
                        //if(argh[i].dead)

                        //argh.RemoveAt (i);
                    }

                    if (argh.Count() == 0)
                        ResetPirates();
                }
                if (argh [i].currentState == EnemyPirate.figureState.died)
                    argh.RemoveAt (i);                  

            }

            map.UpdateCamera(player.GetPosition());
            backGround.Update ();

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

            spriteBatch.Begin (SpriteSortMode.Deferred,
                null,
                SamplerState.PointClamp,
                null,
                null);

            backGround.Draw (spriteBatch);
            map.Draw (spriteBatch);

            foreach (EnemyPirate c in argh)
                c.Draw (spriteBatch);    

            foreach (Coin c in coin)
                c.Draw (spriteBatch);    

            player.Draw (spriteBatch);

            //spriteBatch.DrawString(inGameFont, "speed.Y:" + player.position.Y, new Vector2(20, 20), Color.White);
            spriteBatch.DrawString(inGameFont, "R = Reset", new Vector2(20, 20), Color.White);
            spriteBatch.DrawString(inGameFont, "dist: "+dist.Length()+" "+player.playerLives, new Vector2(20, 40), Color.White);
            spriteBatch.DrawString(inGameFont, ": " + collectedCoins, new Vector2(55, 70), Color.White);
            spriteBatch.Draw (coinCount, new Vector2 (20, 60), Color.White);
            spriteBatch.End();

            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my enemycode:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
namespace TreasureHunt
{
    public class EnemyPirate : PlatformerFigure
    {

        public int enemyLives = 2;
        int animWalk = 0;
        int animHit = 6;
        int animPreDie = 9;
    //  int animDie = 10;
        public figureState currentState;
        public bool dead;
        public bool hurt;
        public const float _delay = 3; // seconds
        public float _remainingDelay = _delay;

        public enum figureState            // Alla olika stadier figuren kan befinna sig i
        {
            standing,
            walking,
            jumping,
            predie,
            die,
            died,
            hitting
        }

        public EnemyPirate (int screenWidth, int screenHeight, ContentManager contMan, Vector2 position, int Lives)
        {
            this.screenWidth = screenWidth;
            this.screenHeight = screenHeight;
            LoadMedia(contMan);
            enemyLives = Lives;

            animSequence = new int[]{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 7, 8, 0, 10, 11, 11 };

            SetBoundingBox (new Rectangle (10, 15, 63, 81));    

            Reset ();
            this.position = position;    
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            Facing = AnimatedObject.direction.left;
            SetFrame(animWalk);
            currentState = figureState.standing;
            maxSpeed = new Vector2(1f, 6);
            //position = new Vector2(1600, 400);   // Behövs inte när man skickar in en position till konstruktorn.
            speed = Vector2.Zero;
            slipperyK = 1;
            acc = Vector2.Zero;                   // Från början står figuren still.
            walkAcc = 1f;
            primaryColor = Color.White;
            alpha = 1;
        }


        private void LoadMedia(ContentManager content)
        {
            gfx = content.Load<Texture2D>("EnemyPirate2");

            AnimationSettings(96, 96, 110, direction.right, 12);
        }

        public override bool Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            var timer = (float) gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
            Think();
            Move(gameTime);
            UpdateAnimation(gameTime);
            GroundCollision();
            if (currentState == figureState.hitting && currentFrame == 0)
                currentState = figureState.standing;
        //  else if (enemyLives <= 0)
            //  currentState = figureState.predie;

            if (currentState == figureState.predie) {
                _remainingDelay -= timer;
                if (_remainingDelay < 2) {
                    alpha -= 0.04f;
                    if (alpha < 0)
                        alpha = 0;
                }
            }

            if (_remainingDelay <= 0)
                currentState = figureState.died;

            return true;
        }

        private void Think()
        {
            if (Facing == direction.left)
            {
                acc.X = -walkAcc;
                if (WallCollision(new Vector2(-10,0)) || !GroundAhead())
                {
                    Facing = direction.right;
                    acc.X = walkAcc;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                acc.X = walkAcc;
                if (WallCollision(new Vector2(10,0)) || !GroundAhead())
                {
                    Facing = direction.left;
                    acc.X = -walkAcc;
                }
            }
        }

        private bool GroundAhead()
        {
            Vector2 ahead = position + pos_feet;        // Vart finns figurens fötter?
            if (Facing == direction.left)
                ahead += new Vector2(-10, 0);           // Tittar lite till vänster om figuren
            else
                ahead += new Vector2(10, 0);            // Tittar lite till höger om figuren

            int tile = Level.GetTile(ahead);

            if (tile > 44 && tile < 77 || tile > 84 && tile < 104)
                return true;

            return false;
        }

        public void EnemyIsDead ()
        {               
            if (currentState == figureState.predie)
                SetFrame (animPreDie);
                acc = Vector2.Zero;
                walkAcc = 0;
                dead = true;   
        }

        public void Hurted()
        {
            if (hurt) {
                var pos = position.X;
                while(position.X < pos-5){
                    position = new Vector2 (position.X, 0);
                }       
            }    
        }

        public void Attack()
        {
            if (currentState != figureState.hitting) {
                SetFrame (animHit);
                currentState = figureState.hitting;
            }   
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve in order to produce a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your code. Noone here is going to check your whole code for possible errors. You should be more precise on your problem and use the debugger to see what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

That's way too much code. You've got no [Asserts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kssw4w7z(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception(v=vs.110).aspx). Make your code super brittle, so that if something wrong happens it will stop and alert you to fix it.

eg. Inside Argh.Attack(), Assert that currentState is not already dead.